# Editing chat line white text on a white background

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I'm seeing white text on a white background when attempting to edit chat.

[image]

Comment: What operating system? Which version of Firefox?

Comment: Windows vista 64bit 3.5.18 wife's laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to see white text on a dark background, similar to what you see in the message that you're editing. Unfortunately, your text area retains its white background even in edit mode. The reason for this seems to be in how the background is specified in the stylesheet.

First, there's a declaration that forces the text area `#input` to have a white background:

```
#input, #chat-body.mob #input-area #bubble #input {
    background-color:white !important;
}
```

Then, when editing, this style block is supposed to take over:

```
.message.editing .content, #input.editing {
    background-color:#666666;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#555555), to(#777777));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #555555, #777777);
    background:linear-gradient(top, #555555, #777777);
    ...
}
```

The `background-color` isn't applied to `#input.editing` though, because of the `!important` rule in the previous block. This ends up being fine in most browsers, since the gradient is taken to be the value of `background-image`, and just overlays the white background. However, gradient support wasn't introduced [until Firefox 3.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient), so your input gets stuck with a solid white background in versions below that.

It's currently unclear whether or not Firefox 3.5 is a [supported browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208), but in any case, adding an `!important` to the `background-color` in the second style block seems to fix the problem.

Comment: absolutely correct